# Size all columns and rows

Tags: c#, format

I need to format all columns and rows with a specific size (like 3, 12.75). I have some code but I need help. Thank you.

I try this:
sheet.SetRowHeight(1, 12.75);
sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 3);

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Range chartRange;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 2] = "";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 3] = "Value 1";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 4] = "Value 2";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5] = "Value 3";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile(@"Test.xls");

Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]; //Get 1st row

sheet.SetRowHeight(1, 20); //Set High
sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 23); // Set Width
```